# NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, nine-patch

I use a nine patch drawable in imageview and using below code I want to get   Bitmap but this error happens.

```
 Bitmap stickerBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) Front.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly cast a `NinePatchDrawable` to a `BitmapDrawable`, since those are two different incompatible drawable types.

If you want to get a Bitmap from a non-BitmapDrawable you have to draw it with a Canvas onto a Bitmap:

```
Drawable drawable = Front.getDrawable();
Bitmap stickerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Front.getWidth(),
        Front.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(stickerBitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Note that your ImageView has to be layouted so that it has a non-zero size.